# Can't read configMap with name: [my-configmap] in namespace:[my-namespace]. Ignoring

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, namespaces, configmap

Deploying the spring application only works in the default namespace. Deploying the same application to other namespaces fails with the following error:

I have noticed this has something to do with the service (named: Kubernetes) in the default namespace which is having the clusterIP of `10.242.0.1`. Deploying the application to other namespaces still routes to this Kubernetes service in the default namespace. Adding service link to this service doesn't help. Creating a replica of this service with endpoints in the other namespaces doesn't solve the issue either.

```
2021-05-13 11:46:24.514  WARN [some-service,,] 1 --- [           main] s.c.k.f.c.Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySource : Can't read configMap with name: [my-configmap] in namespace:[my-namespace]. Ignoring.

io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [ConfigMap]  with name: [my-configmap]  in namespace: [my-namespace]  failed.
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:225) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:186) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:84) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.fabric8.config.Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySource.getData(Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySource.java:62) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-config-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.fabric8.config.Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySource.<init>(Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySource.java:50) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-config-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.fabric8.config.Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySource(Fabric8ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:51) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-config-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.getMapPropertySourceForSingleConfigMap(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:81) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.lambda$locate$0(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:67) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigMapPropertySourceLocator.java:67) [spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:95) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:650) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:403) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at com.ubs.wma.service.accountgroup.AccountGroupServiceApplication.main(AccountGroupServiceApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.242.0.1:443
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:265) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:183) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:133) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.intercept(OIDCTokenRefreshInterceptor.java:41) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:151) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:472) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:435) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:402) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:384) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:935) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:220) ~[kubernetes-client-4.13.2.jar:na]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263) ~[okhttp-3.14.9.jar:na]
        ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Added Role and RoleBinding resources to my deployment like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: namespace-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["configmaps", "pods", "services", "endpoints", "secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]

---

kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: namespace-reader-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: namespace-reader
  apiGroup: ""
```

My bootstrap.yaml config is looking like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        sources:
          - name: some-service
        namespace: ${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}
```

My service deployment is looking like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: some-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: some-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-service
          image: registry/some-service:latest
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 320Mi
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: "some-profile"
            - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 40
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 40
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 10" ]
```

Finally, my configmap looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application-properties.yaml: 'property: "value"'
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: my-configmap
```

Comment: What is your output from `kubectl get configmap my-configmap -n my-namespace` ?

Comment: I get the configmap as expected. The issue is with permission i got to understand. Given a  n admin access using clusterrolebinding to the namespace resolves the issue.

Comment: @BubaConteh glad that you found the solution. Please provide your comment with additional explanation to give it more visibility for future readers and to indicate that the question is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround that works for me. Created an admin clusterrolebinding resource  for my namespace `my-namespace` like so:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding admin-my-namespace --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=my-namespace:default
```

Deleted the Role and the RoleBinding resources as they are not needed any longer.

This works but would appreciate why Role and Rolebinding to ServiceAccount wasn't enough at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Check for network policy configured which blocks accessing it.
If you have network policy configured, port 6443 should be allowed.

policyTypes:
- Egress
egress:
- to:
ports:
- protocol: TCP
port: 6443

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).